# determine how memory is allocated

Tags: php, memory

I've searched around quite a bit, but have been unable to find a functional answer to how best determine how memory is allocated within a script at a point in time.

I'm not looking for memory_get_usage(), which tells me how much memory is being used, but rather am looking for how that memory is allocated -- for example, what variables exist which are consuming memory, and how much they are using. I need this in order to troubleshoot the memory hogs in my script.

Comment: i think you are looking for `get_defined_vars()`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php, which you could loop though and using `memory_get_usage()` and `unset()` you could determine the sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a memory profiler. Take a look at [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof).